# Как в функцию передавать список и на выходе получать результат работы с каждый объектом списка,а не только с последнем?

Tags: python

```
nums = [1, 2, 3]


def word(nums):
    for w in nums:
        pass
    plus = w + 5
    return plus


print(word(nums))
```

как на выходе получать результат работы с каждым числом?

Comment: Что вы хотите получить? Массив чисел?

Comment: чтобы в консоль вывелись столбиком новые числа

Comment: Следовательно, вам нужен цикл, который будет проходиться по числам и делать с ними операции. Верно?

Comment: все именно так.

Comment: ну так и делайте операции с числами в цикле. А то цикл есть, а операций нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю так

```
nums = [1, 2, 3]

def word(nums):
    nums_changed = []
    for w in nums:
        plus = w + 5
        nums_changed.append(plus)
    return nums_changed


print ('\n'.join(word(nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def word(lister):
    for i in range(len(lister)):
        print(lister[i] + 5)
```

Вывод в столбик всех чисел списка с прибавленной пятёркой ‍♂️. Не понимаю о чём вопрос.